# Rayleigh distribution

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

Why do we have to multiple the complex uniformly distributed random variables by \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$, for a Rayleigh distribution. In terms of when we want to transmit data across a Rayleigh distributed channel? (The equation is shown below)

\$ray_{noise}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})*(randn(L,1)+i*randn(L,1))\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for normalization purposes. When you have noise following a circularly-symmetric complex normal distribution, (i.e the real and imaginary part are independent from each other and have the same variance) with a variance of 1 in both parts, the absolute value will be Rayleigh-distributed with a variance of 2. Therefore, when you introduce the factor, the real and imaginary part will have a variance of 1/2 each, resulting in a variance of 1 for the Rayleigh-distributed absolute value.

Edit to adress the question in the comment: Lets call the unit-variance Rayleigh-diastributed noise \$ \tilde{n} \$. Then you can directly set the variance by scaling with a factor \$ \sigma \$:
\$ n = \sigma \cdot \tilde{n} \Rightarrow  \mathrm{var}(n) = \sigma^2 \cdot \mathrm{var}(\tilde{n}) = \sigma^2 \cdot 1  = \sigma^2\$.
Thus, by scaling to unit variance first, you do not have to worry about the original variance anymore and can just scale to the variance you want to have.

Comment: can we tell me, why we normalise noise. If we normalise noise do we also have to normalise the signal power of the transmitted data and lastly what will happen if we dont normalise the noise?